# asterisk notation doesn't work in processing.py?

Tags: python, processing

I use asterisk notation in regular python as:

```
>>> x=(10,11)
>>> y=(12,13)
>>> z=99
>>> print(*x)
10 11
>>> print(*x, *y, z)
10 11 12 13 99
```

But when I try to do similar in python mode of Processing,  it gives me essentially a syntax error: `processing.app.SketchException: Maybe there's an unclosed paren or quote mark somewhere before this line?`

```
p1= (20,20)
p2=(40,40)
c1 = (15,15)
c2 = (50,50)

print(p1)
print(*p1)
# bezier(**p1, **c1, **c2, **p2)
```

Is this not supported in Processing.PY?

Comment: The Python mode of processing has a limited syntax.

Comment: @KlausD. I disagree with your comment, Python mode has *complete* Python 2 working syntax and a very complete Jython implementation of the Python Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, I use it all the time.

```py
p1 = (20, 20)
p2 = (40, 40)

translate(*p1)  # this works

# you can't use "star" unpacking twice like this.
# line(*p1, *p2)  # this won't work!
```

Beware that in Python 2 print is not a function, so I have used `from __future__ import print_function` to make your example work on the image bellow. The print function can handle an arbitrary number of positional arguments, but again, not  * "star" unpacking twice.

I have noticed in your question example `**` which can be used for
keyword arguments & dictionary unpacking. It also works fine overall, but it would not work with the `bezier()` comment you provided. The error message might have misled you.

[image]